# I am unable to build the couchbase ruby gem on os x 10.6.8

Tags: ruby, xcode, gcc, osx-snow-leopard, couchbase

My goal is to install the couchbase ruby gem by building the native extensions, but I am having what seems like an architecture mismatch between the gem and the libcouchbase C library. Here is some background:

- I am running OS X 10.6.8, using rvm, and ruby 1.9.2-p320 built from source
- I was running OS X 10.6.7 and Xcode 3.2.5 up until yesterday but I was unable to build libcouchbase natively
- I then installed brew which is known to help ease the libcouchbase install, and brew told me I needed to upgrade to at least Xcode 3.2.6
- I downloaded the elusive Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard because it was over 2 gigs smaller than 
  Xcode 3.2.6 and I figured I would get the latest version.
- Xcode wouldn't install due to certificate errors which I found were the result of a bug in the System Installer, and the fix was to upgrade to OS X 10.6.8 and then apply a System Update
- A few hours and restarts later, I am running OS X 10.6.8 with XCode 4.2 installed and libcouchbase compiles via brew without any hiccups
- I now attempt to install the couchbase gem but building native extensions fails. It says it is unable to find libcouchbase even when explicitly passing the location of the library
- Inspecting mkmf.log shows the following (**bold emphasis added, but I may be wrong about the problem!**

> "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/universal-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -pipe  -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib   -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -lruby.1.9.1-static  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
>   checked program was:

```
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

> "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/universal-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -pipe  -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  -arch i386 -arch x86_64  -c conftest.c"
>   checked program was:

```
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3:   #include <stdarg.h>
 4:   int foo(int x, ...) {
 5:     va_list va;
 6:     va_start(va, x);
 7:     va_arg(va, int);
 8:     va_arg(va, char *);
 9:     va_arg(va, double);
10:     return 0;
11:   }
12:   int main() {
13:     return foo(10, "", 3.14);
14:     return 0;
15:   }
/* end */
```

> have_library: checking for libcouchbase_server_versions() in -lcouchbase... -------------------- no
>
> "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/universal-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -pipe  -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib   -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -lruby.1.9.1-static -lcouchbase  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
>   **ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_libcouchbase_server_versions", referenced from:
>         _t in cckhpWpO.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386**
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/AT/ATO2AJa-G3Ogm+J4qma1hE+++TI/-Tmp-/mkmf_20120724-40695-16d2a4n/ccAGPue9.out (No such file or directory)
>   checked program was:

```
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))libcouchbase_server_versions; return 0; }
/* end */
```

> "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/universal-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fno-common -pipe  -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.19/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/usr/lib -L/Users/emkman/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib   -arch i386 -arch x86_64   -lruby.1.9.1-static -lcouchbase  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
>   conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
>   conftest.c:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘libcouchbase_server_versions’
>   conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
>   conftest.c:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘libcouchbase_server_versions’
>   lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/AT/ATO2AJa-G3Ogm+J4qma1hE+++TI/-Tmp-/mkmf_20120724-40695-cblicr/ccG9E6Cp.out
>   checked program was:

```
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <libcouchbase/couchbase.h>
4: 
5: /*top*/
6: int main() {return 0;}
7: int t() { libcouchbase_server_versions(); return 0; }
/* end */
```

---

So it seems to me that the problem is that gcc is looking for an i386 build of /usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.dylib and inspecting mine shows

> /usr/local/lib/libcouchbase.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

So now to my question(s). Is this the problem or a red herring? Do I need to be building libcouchbase as i386 or universal, or is the problem on the gem side? I have been building native gem extensions on this system for many years without problem, including the sometimes nasty mysql gem, but now I have new versions of GCC/Xcode. The rvm release notes say that Xcode 4.2 only works with Ruby 1.9.3 and breaks lots of native extensions, so I completely uninstalled it and then installed GCC-10.6.pkg from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/ which rvm recommends as a working, but I still have the same problem. Here is my brew --env dump:

> CC: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>
> CXX: /usr/bin/llvm-g++ => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
>
> LD: /usr/bin/llvm-gcc => /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>
> CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4.1 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
>
> CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4.1 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
>
> CPPFLAGS: -isystem /usr/local/include
>
> LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
>
> MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.6
>
> MAKEFLAGS: -j2

Both now and when I had Xcode 4.2 installed, my -march was set to *core2*. Should this be *native* instead? I rebuilt ruby 1.9.2-p320 from source, via rvm/JewelryBox after installing my latest osx-gcc toolchain, to ensure it was using the same flags. It is built as universal-darwin and seems correct:

```
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "1.9.2p320"
date:         "2012-04-20"
platform:     "universal.x86_64-darwin10.8.0"
patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35421"
full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [universal.x86_64-darwin10.8.0]"
```

I know this is a lot of info, but I just want to be thorough with the details and show that I have tried *almost* everything. I should also mention that I have tried the developer preview of the gem combined with the developer preview of libcouchbase, and the error is the same. The two things I haven't tried:

1. Installing XCode 4.1 for Snow Leopard - Apple no longer makes this file available for download even though it is theoretically supported.
2. Installing Xcode 3.2.6 for Snow Leopard - I was trying to avoid the 4gb download but I have just started it now and can try it later tonight

Any help is greatly appreciated, especially if you have built the couchbase gem on OS X before.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good question, as I remember going through some similar pains trying to build the gem myself. However that was a while ago and I don't have the files etc handy to remember what I did or if my errors looked like yours.

I know it's not as good as a direct answer, but I think you should be able to get in touch with the gem author here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/couchbase or via @avsej on Twitter.

Comment: I ended up installing a new ruby 1.9.3 (via rvm) that built as 64 bit only. This was then able to build the 64 bit gem and use the 64 bit libcouchbase. I guess moving forward I can't and really shouldn't need to worry about building 32 bit gems/libraries. We shall see. Thanks for the help. edit: I should also mention that I emailed the author about something else, and he did respond and was helpful, so thank you to @avsej for everything as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps, this resolved the issue for me:

```
brew unlink libcouchbase
brew install libcouchbase@2
brew link --force --overwrite libcouchbase@2
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Then try the bundle install or gem install.

```
bundle install
```